# Kubernetes networking with ingress-nginx

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Suppose to have a Kubernetes worker node with a private IP address.
I want to expose some services as web services and  a MongoDB database.
Can I assign to ingress or ingress-nginx controller a public IP on a host having a private IP? Something as docker IP VLan L2/L3? I have to use an additional plug-in as CALICO?

Comment: Are you using Kubernetes on-premises or in a private cloud?

Comment: I use Kubernites on-premise.